# How do I extract leadgen_id from the below JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json, decode

JSON

```
    {  
   "entry":[  
      {  
         "changes":[  
            {  
               "field":"leadgen",
               "value":{  
                  "created_time":1499940591,
                  "page_id":"160135091155811",
                  "form_id":"151012182128929",
                  "leadgen_id":"153650938531720"
               }
            }
         ],
         "id":"160135091155811",
         "time":1499940592
      }
   ],
   "object":"page"
}
```

PHP Code:

```
$json= file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($json);
echo $input['entry']['changes']['leadgen_id'];
```

How do I extract the leadgen_id? I tried many combinations, all give an error.

The only output I get is ">". I have checked all the open tags and balanced everything, still getting error.

Comment: json_decode has a second parameter if you want the result to be an array: [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Try this way    echo $input->entry[0]->changes[0]->value->leadgen_id ;

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick, worked like a charm! I wasted so much time on this and it turned out to be so simple!